# Given a byte buffer, dtype, shape and strides, how to create Numpy ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, buffer

I have a buffer, dtype, shape and strides. I want to create a Numpy ndarray which reuses the memory of the buffer.

There is [`numpy.frombuffer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) which creates a 1D array from a buffer and reuses the memory. However, I'm not sure if I can easily and safely reshape it and set the strides.

There is the [`numpy.ndarray` constructor](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) which can refer to a buffer but I'm not sure if it will reuse the memory or if it will copy it (it's not clear from the documentation).

So, will the `numpy.ndarray` constructor do what I want? Or what can I use instead?

---

Ok, so I'm trying to figure out myself now what the `numpy.ndarray` constructor is really doing. The code is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/945c308e96fb815729e8f8aeb0ad6b39b8bdf84a/numpy/core/src/multiarray/arrayobject.c#L1623). It uses `PyArray_BufferConverter` to convert the buffer argument. Then it will call `PyArray_NewFromDescr_int` which can be seen [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/08fc49e1b33e4da9e14e375f399ba92c615eb569/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L899). If data is passed in there, it will [`fa->flags &= ~NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA;`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/08fc49e1b33e4da9e14e375f399ba92c615eb569/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L1072).

Comment: Aren't you just asking for ways to make a `view`?  I'd suggest studying the `lib/stride_tricks` file.  `as_strided` is a handy tool making a view with a specific shape and strides.  But beware that numpy code using your view might end up making a copy.

Comment: @hpaulj: I see. The code is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py#L38). That exactly answers my question (well at least together with `numpy.frombuffer` which will be a view). You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by @hpaulj, you can accomplish this using the stride_tricks module.  You need both `np.frombuffer` and `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`:

#### Gather data from NumPy array

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: x = np.random.random((3, 4)).astype(dtype='f4')
In [3]: buffer = x.data
In [4]: dtype = x.dtype
In [5]: shape = x.shape
In [6]: strides = x.strides
```

#### Recreate NumPy array

```
In [7]: xx = np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype)
In [8]: xx = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(xx, shape, strides)
```

#### Verify results

```
In [9]: x
Out[9]: 
array([[ 0.75343359,  0.20676662,  0.83675659,  0.99904215],
       [ 0.37182721,  0.83846378,  0.6888299 ,  0.57195812],
       [ 0.39905572,  0.7258808 ,  0.88316005,  0.2187883 ]], dtype=float32)

In [10]: xx
Out[10]: 
array([[ 0.75343359,  0.20676662,  0.83675659,  0.99904215],
       [ 0.37182721,  0.83846378,  0.6888299 ,  0.57195812],
       [ 0.39905572,  0.7258808 ,  0.88316005,  0.2187883 ]], dtype=float32)

In [11]: x.strides
Out[11]: (16, 4)
In [12]: xx.strides
Out[12]: (16, 4)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use either method - neither of them will generate a copy:

```
s = b'aaabaaacaaadaaae'
a1 = np.frombuffer(s, np.int32, 4).reshape(2, 2)
a2 = np.ndarray((2, 2), np.int32, buffer=s)

print(a1.flags.owndata, a1.base.tostring())
# (False, b'aaabaaacaaadaaae')
print(a2.flags.owndata, a2.base)
# (False, b'aaabaaacaaadaaae')
```

Note that neither array can be modified in place, since they are backed by read-only memory:

```
a1[:] = 0  # ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
```

Comment: Neither of them work for me in numpy 1.18 and python3: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: @Koshmaar I originally wrote that answer for Python2. In Python3 `s` would be unicode rather than bytes (I've changed it to a bytes literal).

Answer (score 2):

I'd stick with `frombuffer` because it's intended directly for this purpose, and makes it clear what you're doing.  Here's an example:

```
In [58]: s0 = 'aaaa'   # a single int32

In [59]: s1 = 'aaabaaacaaadaaae'  # 4 int32s, each increasing by 1

In [60]: a0 = np.frombuffer(s0, dtype='>i4', count=1)   # dtype sets the stride

In [61]: print a0
[1633771873]

In [62]: a1 = np.frombuffer(s, dtype='>i4', count=4)

In [63]: print a1
[1633771874 1633771875 1633771876 1633771877]

In [64]: a2 = a1.reshape((2,2))   # do a reshape, which also sets the strides

In [65]: print a2
[[1633771874 1633771875]
 [1633771876 1633771877]]

In [66]: a2 - a0     # do some calculation with the reshape
Out[66]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]], dtype=int32)
```

Is there something you need that this doesn't do?

Comment: I want to set some custom strides.

Comment: I like from `frombuffer` because the name makes it clear to the future reader what you're our doing.  If you want to set the strides, you could do that after you open your buffer, as I do here.  Both the `dtype` and `reshape` do set the strides, and if you want to set some unusual strides, you can do that using `stride_tricks`, but without some specification of this in the question, I'll just leave this at the normal stride settings (length and shape).

Comment: I said so in the question "Given a ... and strides". So obviously I want that it uses the given strides.